# How to extract numbers from text file using Windows batch file 2021?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to do the following:
I have a text file input.txt with the following content: (with special characters). I want to extract a sequence of numbers starting with "1000..." into a file output.txt( Link file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/yu389g2g68vu9gk/input.txt/file)

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
     secret  0c0d5668f02a18035e21303b8e93e895  is_imported  
is_guest_user  username 100071366110180 access_token ÌEAAAAUaZA8jlABALsVDH8f0XiI8uvKLzBFcEOVXWKweUAGowUD337Ezl8RGrBoYG5ZBxGgIcyGhhMZAtYz20pV6VDLZBoVZAKckefM3WAcZBSk0oa4h14EtcGDJrnHctxQcXJCmC0ZALxZAJvEZBZAIZADXmRW57uLjnxTvHLsUfDfZBJG6xAP6TL91M7KZACzzZAp2YjEZD analytics_claim 5hmac.AR16ZZiQ4McOWMORPml4l34CCKJ16Exv3PGlwu8hTjP1m5QD uid 100071366110180 session_key -5.X08JoU7eWcFk-Q.1629018221.5-100071366110180 session_cookies_string#[{"name":"c_user","value":"100071366110180","expires":"Mon, 15 Aug 2022 09:03:41 GMT","expires_timestamp":1660554221,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true},{"name":"xs","value":"5:X08JoU7eWcFk-Q:2:1629018221:-1:-1","expires":"Mon, 15 Aug 2022 09:03:41 GMT","expires_timestamp":1660554221,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"fr","value":"1UaJxofwAmFd1GJ73.AWWzFCKkoLqrEIhhmnwRRp93G1Q.BhGNht.k-.AAA.0.0.BhGNht.AWXmGu_qVdY","expires":"Sat, 13 Nov 2021 09:03:38 GMT","expires_timestamp":1636794218,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"datr","value":"W9gYYbPrISL4vu0V_JtH2uUf","expires":"Tue, 15 Aug 2023 09:03:41 GMT","expires_timestamp":1692090221,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true}]
```

Here is the code I tried but didn't get the expected result:

````
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "1000" input.txt') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   set "tenChars=!line:~0,100!"
   rem If R0621 was in first 10 characters
   if "!tenChars:1000=!" neq "!tenChars!" (
      echo !line!
   )
)) > output.txt ```
````

Comment: As your content has not been displayed correctly, can you please [edit] your question, to tell us what the file encoding is? and also what type of line endings it uses? It may also assist if you could upload a copy of the file somewhere, to ensure that willing helpers can download it without modification or corruption and work with the correct data.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr "input.txt" "1000"') do set "LINE=%%I" & for /F %%J in ('cmd /V /C echo/!LINE:*1000=1000!') do echo %%J`?

Comment: this is link download file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/yu389g2g68vu9gk/input.txt/file

Comment: @aschipfl tks u. but it is error "%%I was unexpected at this time"

Comment: If you try it directly in Command Prompt rather than in a batch file, you have to use `%I` and `%J` rather than `%%I` and `%%J`…

Comment: @aschipfl i try it. and it alert error "FINDSTR: Cannot open 1000". can you give me 1 complete script to output output.txt. for example file.bat
thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, it should read `findstr "1000" "input.txt"` (first search string, then file spec.)…

Comment: @aschipfl did you try it out, i tried again and it says "!LINE:*1000" . please try it worked fine, thanks b

Comment: The file you have uploaded is not, regardless of the extension you have given it, a plain text file. Please provide us with the real details of that file, how it was created, by which process(es) or application(s) etc. It is clear that the end of the file, at least, is JSON data, which should normally be UTF-8 without a BOM, however the beginning of the file does not appear to be JSON. I must therefore assume that this file is a merging of more than one file with different encodings / BOMS and as a result is not valid for general use, I would call it corrupted.

Comment: it's taken from android phone, facebook app's cookie file. I use the following command to get it:
adb shell "su -c 'cat /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_light_prefs/com.facebook.katana/authentication'" >cookie.txt (it is input.txt)

Comment: Just because you've decided to give it a `.txt` extension, does not make it a plain text file. And even if it was, because it was created on a Unix based OS, it will have used LF line endings, not CRLF, as used in Windows.

Comment: oh. I do not understand very much. but I think it can still be handled by filtering out special characters,..

Comment: Sorry, I did not try it, but it seems I forgot some quotes; this *should* do it now: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr "1000" "input.txt"') do set "LINE=%%I" & for /F %%J in ('cmd /V /C "echo/!LINE:*1000=1000!"') do echo %%J`

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you for replying and helping me. but it seems your code still not working, hope you will try again and send me when it works successfully. i tried again and got the result "!LINE:*1000=1000!"

Comment: Alright, so this time I found the time to try it; I missed to escape the `=`, so it must be this: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr "1000" "input.txt"') do set "LINE=%%I" & for /F %%J in ('cmd /V /C "echo/!LINE:*1000^=1000!"') do echo %%J`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked fine. You are very good. Wishing you a lot of health and luck. Wish you always happy!!!
I have completed your code to save the output.txt as extract.bat file:
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr "1000" "input.txt"') do set "LINE=%%I" & for /F %%J in ('cmd /V /C "echo) /!LINE:*1000^=1000!"') do echo %%J>>output.txt
and the content of output.txt is: "!LINE:*1000=1000!
100068096021967"
Can you help me further so that the save result is only "100068096021967"?

Comment: You're welcome! Place `@echo off` at the top of your script, then replace `>>` with `>` to not append to but overwrite the output file…

Comment: @aschipfl thanks. but the result is "100068096021967♣
"
There is a special character after the number

Comment: If the character is always the same, replace `for /F %%J` by `for /F "delims=# " %%J` where `#` represents that character; maybe `chcp 437` somewhere on top of the script could help since it is probably an extended character; if it is a Unicode character, then, well, I would not use a batch script at all but something else (PowerShell, VBScript, JScript, etc.), which supports such character encodings…

Comment: @aschipfl sorry to bother.
My input.txt file had some changes and the code failed to find "1000". Can you help me fix the code.
the new file input.txt has 2 more lines at the top: 
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
     secret  0c0d5668f02a18035e21303b8e93e895  is_imported  
is_guest_user  username 100071366110180 access_token ......

Comment: It seems you need the `skip` option of [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)…

Comment: @aschipfl Can you give me the complete code?

Comment: @aschipfl pleas help me

Comment: Insert `skip=2` into the option string of `for /F` in order to skip the first two lines, and that is it; also check out the link I provided…

Comment: @aschipfl tks u. Is it possible to search through all the text, since the number of lines in the file can change.

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. But since there is `findstr` there should be no need for skipping lines, because it should only return the required line. Perhaps you have to reconsider the search string…

Comment: @aschipfl I don't know how to review it. my search string is still "1000xxxxxxxxxxxx" 16 consecutive numbers. If you are still interested in my question, can I have the complete code?. If you're not interested anymore, that's okay. Anyway thank you very much for your help in the previous questions.

Comment: Well, it's impossible for me to provide a complete script, particularly because of not knowing the exact file format and the fact that it's binary data. But I can provide another hint: [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) supports a tiny subset of regular expressions which could help: `[0-9]` matches a decimal digit, `[0-9][0-9]` matches two, and so on; so you could build a better search string than just `1000` to find the line of interest without having to skip any…

Comment: @aschipfl tks u. I managed to do that. didn't think I could do it, thank you very much. Here is the code that works fine:
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr / R "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0- 9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" "input .txt"') do set "LINE=%%I" & for /F "delims= " %%J in ('cmd /V /C "echo/!LINE:*1000^=1000!"') do echo %%J>output.txt

Comment: @aschipfl can you help me? how to exit For F loop when first result is found?

Comment: Please use the search facility on top of of this site! you will find out that you can break out of a `for` loop by `goto`. *N. B.:* I would not use `[0-9]` patterns for the first four figures when it is clear that they are always `1000`…

Comment: @aschipfl. ok tks u.Can I convert the ANSI format txt file to UTF-8 with cmd?